# File upload field with create contact in Sugar CRM

Tags: sugarcrm

I want to create a file upload field with a browse button under "create contact" section of Sugar CRM.

I have already tried to create some relationship with Document module and Contact module but that is not something what I am looking for. I want a browse button in the contact section itself.

I have searched many forums and groups but no value. Expect some correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save your time/money by going with off-the-shelf solutions: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/file-upload-module

If it's for a personal exercise just to figure it out check out these links:

- http://forums.sugarcrm.com/f162/how-create-file-type-upload-document-80554/#post305936
- [making a file type field in sugarcrm custom module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547886/making-a-file-type-field-in-sugarcrm-custom-module)

Answer (score 0):

Custom file upload in module is well explained here.

http://www.technologyworkshops.net/php/custom-multiple-file-upload-sugarcrm-t129.html